# DWH Design. Is denormalization a best approach or it should be avoided?

Tags: sas, data-modeling, data-warehouse

I'm re-designing a Data Mart in SAS that will be used for a profiling engine (deterministic) and later fed, denormalized, to SAS Visual Analytics.
Let me explain the domain: this is a call center, I have some tickets (facts) coming in every day with associated the caller id and a client id (this isn't  explained very well but this two entities may or may not be the same individual)
Inside this two tables I have the ssn field that some other tables from different external systems have as primary key (in this domain this value is unique and identify an individual).

To recap:
ticket_table n->1 caller_table 1*->1 ssn_table(s)
ticket_table n->1 client_table 1*->1 ssn_table(s)

So I was thinking to consolidate all this tables with different informations about the individual in a single ssn_table with all relevant information (avoiding duplicates and flagging misaligned variables  from different systems) and then either:

- linking this table with the two "inner dimensions" caller and client
- extracting the ssn from caller and client directly into the fact table so that I can keep 1 level of normalization by creating this two variables "ssn_client" and "ssn_caller" as foreing keys to the ssn_table

All this dimension will keep the history and I'm thinking of modelling them as SCD Type 2 (right now the "model" consist of all the tables loaded as-is in SAS updating old existing data, no history, not even for the fact table (a ticket is updated with the close_date when closed)

What do you think is the best approach (or maybe suggest a better one) ? I'm leaning towards the second option, but I'm afraid it will slow down the ETL process a lot

Some numbers:
Fact Table: 100M rows
caller&client: 24M and 28M rows
ssn: unsure, lets say 80M, many ssn don't appear in caller and/or client but there is the need to include them in the model.

Updates:
about 100k tickets daily, some of which may be from new callers about new clients or modify information of existing ones.
no idea on how many new/updated ssn from the different systems for the moment

Comment: You know that SSN are not unique and do not follow the requirements of a primary key?

Comment: Should have been more precise. It's called SSN but it's not USA social security number. Let's assume it's unique in this domain and when it's not  it's a data quality problem (that we will try to handle). Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: I'd probably use a snowflake schema for my SSN table, and leverage SAS formats on the other side which help reduce some of the labelling/joining burden.

Comment: FYI - this probably isn't a valid SO question and you'll get better answers posting on communities.sas.com as there are data engineers and developers over there. Post in the Data Management/Admin forum.